# iOS Google Play Service's push notifications is working at this time?

Tags: google-play-games

I'm building an iOS game using Google Play Game for turn-based multiplayer but cannot receive any notifications. I did research many days to find what is wrong but i can't find anything.

So is iOS push notification in Google Play game still working at this time? Do your games still receive push notifications normally? Please provide me some information.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is still indicated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/turnbasedMultiplayer) that invitation and turn notifications are currently supported on Android and iOS. Based from this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/notifications), you need to register your app to receive push notifications.

In your `appDelegate`, add the following code to the callback for retrieving the push device token passed back from APNS. This device token is used for outbound push notifications, and your app must register it with the Google Play games services push service. Make sure to always register your device token through `GPGManager` to enable push notifications from Google Play games services. Even if the user has not signed in; the `GPGmanager` object will cache this token and save it until the user signs in.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
        didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
        :(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"Got deviceToken from APNS! %@", deviceToken);
    [[GPGManager sharedInstance] registerDeviceToken:deviceToken
            forEnvironment:GPGPushNotificationEnvironmentSandbox];
}
```

From this [related thread](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/566):

> If you are having issues you might want to make sure the token is being registered correctly with APNS in the `AppController.m` (by logging it).
>
> Also, there are two certificates you can register on the Play console, one for sandbox and one for production. Make sure that certificate you are using is the one being configured. By default the AppController calls
> `gpg::RegisterDeviceToken(deviceToken, false);` which indicates that this is the prod certificate configured on the console.

You can also check this [related GitHub issue](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/606) which might help.